# while loop with hasNextInt() finishes, but program does not do anything after it

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I have this program here:

```
ArrayList<Integer> meh = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Input 3 numbers: ");

while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    meh.add(sc.nextInt());
    System.out.println("meeeeeep");
}

System.out.println("Goodbye");
```

Output (if 3 integers are inputed):

```
meeeeeep
meeeeeep
meeeeeep
```

It doesn't print the goodbye message, or do anything that I put after it.

Answer (score 4):

That's because the scanner is waiting for the coming input. `sc.hasNextInt()` is waiting for the next token and to determine if it is a int.

To solve this, try reading by line and split on `" "` using `String.split();`

Another solution might be to do this in a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    meh.add(sc.nextInt());
    System.out.println("meeeeeep");
}
```

Comment: There is no need for a while loop if you know how many integers to expect. The for loop solution is much better.

Comment: Another solution would be reading from file or piping the input.