# Program Hangs after scanner.hasNextInt()

Tags: java, integer, java.util.scanner

I am using the Scanner.hasNextInt() to get space separated integers from my console:

Input:
 1 2 3 4 5

But the program just hangs after reading the value 5. I have tried debugging this but the blue debugger also disappears after reading 5 and never advances to the next line. Any help is appreciated. Below is my code:

```
 package cracking.code;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>>{

Node<T> left;

Node<T> right;

T data;

public Node(T data){
    this.data = data;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}

public void insert(T value){

    if(value.compareTo(data)<=0){
        if(left == null){
            left = new Node<T>(value);
        }
        else{
            left.insert(value);
        }
    }
    else{
        if(right == null){
            right = new Node<T>(value);
        }
        else{
            right.insert(value);
        }
    }
}

public boolean contains(T value){
    if(value.compareTo(data) == 0){
        return true;
    }
    else if(value.compareTo(data)<0){
        return (left == null)?false:left.contains(value);
    }
    else{
        return (right == null)?false:right.contains(value);
    }
}

public void printInOrder(){
    if(left != null){
        left.printInOrder();
    }
    System.out.println(data+" ");
    if(right != null){
        right.printInOrder();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Node<Integer> root = new Node<Integer>(scanner.nextInt());
    while(scanner.hasNextInt()){

        int value = scanner.nextInt();
        root.insert(value);

    }

    root.printInOrder();

    scanner.close();
}
}
```

I just modified my program to get the number of integers using a for loop. I am giving the value of n as 5 and enter the integers : 1 2 3 4 5..still the program just freezes in the for loop when i = 4:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.println("Enter the number of values:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the values using space separation: ");
    Node<Integer> root = new Node<Integer>(scanner.nextInt());
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){


        int value = scanner.nextInt();
        root.insert(value);

    }
    System.out.println("Out of the damn for loop");
```

Comment: If you input the line via stdin you should send a CRTL-D to mark the end of your input.

Comment: please share Node class as well I tried without it and it worked.
public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(scanner.hasNextInt()){

            int value = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println(value);

        }
        scanner.close();

    }

Comment: @ManojYadav: Delete the lines using nodes and it will run.

Comment: @macmoonshine I tried same thing see code in comments.It works:) Wanted to check if something to do with Node class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [while loop with hasNextInt() finishes, but program does not do anything after it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101345/while-loop-with-hasnextint-finishes-but-program-does-not-do-anything-after-it)

Comment: You might want to take stacktraces in order to find the actual call that is blocking: start the program, enter "5" and once it hangs execute `jstack <PID>`. The PID of the program can be determined in various ways, e.g. via `jps`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour when you use `System.in` as the underlying `PrintStream`.

`System.in` is basically the console that the user can type in. When you ask `System.in` whether it has a next integer, it asks the user whether he/she wants to enter more stuff. So it waits there and asks you for input.

You can say "no I don't want to input any more stuff" by pressing Ctrl+D or Command+D.

Alternatively, you can tell the user that entering a certain number will mean that he/she does not want to input any more stuff. You can then check for this and `break` out of the loop.

Tip: calling `close` on a `Scanner` with `System.in` as the underlying stream is not such a good idea. Your program will crash when you try to read more stuff from it after it has been closed.

Comment: I just modified my program to get the number of integers using a for loop. I am giving the value of n as 5 and enter the integers : 1 2 3 4 5..still the program just freezes in the for loop when i = 4:

Comment: @VishwaBhat You got an off-by-1 error here! You've already got an integer as the root (line 7 of the edited code). And `n` is 5 so you are getting 5 _more_ integers. Change the for loop condition to `i < n -1`.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(" *");;

         Node<Integer> root = new Node<Integer>(scanner.nextInt());
         while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
             int value = scanner.nextInt();
             root.insert(value);
         }
         scanner.close();

         root.printInOrder();
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(scanner.hasNextInt()){

            int value = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println(value);

        }
        scanner.close();

    }
```